# PyQt5. Изменить число знаков после запятой в ячейке QDoubleSpinBox в QTableView

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, sqlite3, pyqt

Есть проблема с отображением значений из БД `SQLite3` в `QSqlTableView`. Как видно из кода, в базу загружаем числа с **3** знаками после запятой, но при отображении в `QSqlTableView` по дефолту для их отображения в ячейке, ставиться `QDoubleSpinBox` и автоматически округляет значения до **2** знаков.
Соответственно при редактировании чисел, в базу записываются числа только с **2** знаками.

Можно ли как то перегрузить `QDoubleSpinBox` или переустановить `setDecimals` для данного элемента, или вообще сделать так, чтобы в таблицу для отображения значений типа *real* устанавливался не `QDoubleSpinBox`, а обычный `lineEdit`?

Код прилагаю:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtSql
import sys
import sqlite3


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()
        
        self.create_table()
        self.open_table()             
        
    def initUI(self):
        self.my_dbtable_view = QtWidgets.QTableView(self)
        self.my_dbtable_view.resize(490,200)
        self.my_dbtable_view.move(5,5)
      
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 500, 210)
        self.setWindowTitle('Title')        
        self.show()    

    def create_table(self):
        connect = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
        cursor = connect.cursor()
        try:
            cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE test_table (lenght REAL)')
            new_list = [round(x * 0.001, 3) for x in range(1500000,1500500)]
            for elem in new_list:
                cursor.execute('INSERT INTO test_table VALUES ({0})'.format(elem))
                connect.commit()
            cursor.close()
            connect.close()                
        except sqlite3.OperationalError:
            pass
            
    def open_table(self):
        self.con = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
        self.con.setDatabaseName(r'.\test.db')
        self.con.open()  
        
        self.stm = QtSql.QSqlTableModel(parent = None)
        self.stm.setTable('test_table')
        self.stm.setSort(1, QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)
        self.stm.select()
        
        self.stm.setHeaderData(0, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, 'Lenght')
        self.my_dbtable_view.setModel(self.stm)  
        self.my_dbtable_view.setColumnWidth(0, 100)

        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Опубликуйте пожалуйста минимальный пример демонстрирующий вашу проблему.

Comment: @S. Nick Пример, имеется ввиду результат? Скрин таблицы сделать не могу, но по сути получается в базе значение 13241.457 (int), а при вставке модели в самой программе выводится значение 13241.46

Comment: я вижу вы разместили данный вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56893148/pyqt5-change-number-of-characters-after-comma-in-cell-qdoublespinbox-in-qtablev  . Не могли бы вы мне ответить, мои ответы не решают вашу проблему или вы желаете видеть альтернативные решения?

Comment: @S. Nick Ваши ответы к сожалению не решают данную проблему, т.к. в них вы пользуетесь QTableWidget, где есть метод setItemDelegateForColumn, к сожалению в QSqlTableView у меня не получается его использовать, иначе проблема была бы уже решена

Comment: я сожалею, что потратил какое-то время. Но мой второй пример использует  `self.my_dbtable_view = QtWidgets.QTableView(self)` из вашего реального примера. Посмотрите внимательно.

Comment: @S.Nick ох, извините, серьёзно, не заметил обновления, вашего ответа! Сейчас всё проверил, работает!!!) Спасибо огромное за помощь и потраченное на меня время)

Comment: @S.Nick Вы гений!! Дали второе дыхание для написания моей программы, т.к. всё упиралось именно в этот момент!!!

Comment: Удачи вам. Но будьте внимательны.

Comment: @S.Nick, чтобы не создавать новых тем, не подскажете ещё один момент, как убрать округление в самой Qtableview? Получается теперь при выводе визуально округляет значения сама таблица, но при редактировании в делегате всё как нужно

Comment: я не могу на слух представить что и как где-то происходит. Также не рекомендовано в комментариях задавать вопросы. Сформируйте новый вопрос, прикрепляйте пример демонстрирующий проблему и вам постараются помочь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> QDoubleSpinBox Class
>
> decimals : int
>
> Устанавливает, сколько десятичных знаков будет использовать спинбокс для отображения

Дополнительная информация здесь: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdoublespinbox.html#decimals-prop

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class DoubleDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(parent, decimals=3)             # <--- decimals=3
        editor.setFrame(False)
        editor.setMinimum(-1.7976931348623157e308)
        editor.setMaximum(1.7976931348623157e308)
        editor.setSizePolicy(
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Ignored, editor.sizePolicy().verticalPolicy()
        )
        return editor

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        
        self.tablewidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(4, 3)
        self.tablewidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(
            ["X", "Y", "Результат"] 
        )
        self.tablewidget.itemChanged.connect(self.on_itemChanged)
        
        for col in (0, 1): 
            delegate = DoubleDelegate(self.tablewidget)
            self.tablewidget.setItemDelegateForColumn(col, delegate)

        self.setCentralWidget(self.tablewidget)

        self.calculates = [
            {
                "inputs": (0, 1),
                "output": 2,
                "function": lambda x, y: x ** 2 + y ** 2,
            },
        ]

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot("QTableWidgetItem*")
    def on_itemChanged(self, item):
        for c in self.calculates:
            inputs   = c["inputs"]
            output   = c["output"]
            function = c["function"]
            if item.column() in inputs:
                self.calculate(item.row(), *inputs, output, function)

    def calculate(self, row, in1, in2, out, function):
        self.tablewidget.blockSignals(True)
        for col in (in1, in2, out):
            it = self.tablewidget.item(row, col)
            if it is None:
                it = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("0")
                self.tablewidget.setItem(row, col, it)
        self.tablewidget.blockSignals(False)
        it_in1 = self.tablewidget.item(row, in1)
        it_in2 = self.tablewidget.item(row, in2)
        val_in1 = float(it_in1.text())
        val_in2 = float(it_in2.text())
        result = function(val_in1, val_in2)
        it_out = self.tablewidget.item(row, out)
        it_out.setText(str(result))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

По сути это обновление отличается от предыдущего примера ОДНОЙ строкой.

```
import sys
import sqlite3
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtSql


class DoubleDelegate(QtWidgets.QStyledItemDelegate):
    def createEditor(self, parent, option, index):
        editor = QtWidgets.QDoubleSpinBox(parent, decimals=3)                      # <--- decimals=3
        editor.setFrame(False)
        editor.setMinimum(-1.7976931348623157e308)
        editor.setMaximum(1.7976931348623157e308)
        editor.setSizePolicy(
            QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Ignored, editor.sizePolicy().verticalPolicy()
        )
        return editor
        

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

        self.create_table()
        self.open_table()             

    def initUI(self):

        self.my_dbtable_view = QtWidgets.QTableView(self)
        self.my_dbtable_view.resize(490,200)
        self.my_dbtable_view.move(5,5)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 500, 210)
        self.setWindowTitle('Title')        
        self.show()    

    def create_table(self):
        connect = sqlite3.connect('testDoubleSpinBox.db')      # ! testDoubleSpinBox       
        cursor = connect.cursor()
        try:
        
#            cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE test_table (lenght REAL)')
            cursor.execute('CREATE TABLE test_table (lenght varchar(20))')             # <-----
            
            new_list = [round(x * 0.001, 3) for x in range(1500000,1500500)]
            for elem in new_list:
                cursor.execute('INSERT INTO test_table VALUES ({0})'.format(elem))
                connect.commit()
            cursor.close()
            connect.close()                
        except sqlite3.OperationalError:
            pass

    def open_table(self):
        self.con = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
        self.con.setDatabaseName(r'.\testDoubleSpinBox.db')       # ! testtDoubleSpinBox
        self.con.open()  

        self.stm = QtSql.QSqlTableModel(parent = None)
        self.stm.setTable('test_table')
        self.stm.setSort(1, QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)
        self.stm.select()

        self.stm.setHeaderData(0, QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, 'Lenght')
        
        self.my_dbtable_view.setModel(self.stm)  
        
        self.my_dbtable_view.setColumnWidth(0, 100)
        
### vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv   
        delegate = DoubleDelegate(self.my_dbtable_view)
        self.my_dbtable_view.setItemDelegateForColumn(0, delegate)
### ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^       
        

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Про делегаты знаю, но вопрос применения не для QTableWidget, а для QTableView, а если брать точнее, то QtSql.QSqlTableModel. Извиняюсь за задержку с ответом

Comment: @vladuxa_23 предоставьте пожалуйста минимальный пример демонстрирующий вашу проблему.

Comment: <img src="https://pp.userapi.com/c850332/v850332468/1883b1/6ufhrE0i_YQ.jpg"> код указан в вопросе, проблема в том, что в БД число храниться как REAL, с точностью 3 знака после запятой. В таблице при отображении в программе оно сначала отображается с 3 знаками после запятой, НО, если мы решим редактировать значение в ячейке, то при двойном клике число помещается в QDoubleSpinBox и автоматически округляется до 2х символов

Comment: @vladuxa_23 вы пробовали     `QDoubleSpinBox.setDecimals(int prec)`  ?

Comment: @vladuxa_23 То что вы опубликовали - это не минимальный пример. Нужен приме, который скопировав, воспроизведет вашу проблему.

Comment: отредактировал вопрос в шапке, добавил код, демонстрирующий мою проблему

Comment: @vladuxa_23 я добавил пример, надеюсь поможет.